# Convert a office document on the client side

Tags: javascript, pdf, ms-office

I have a project that I will be researching and hopefully implementing soon. One of the biggest hurdles, that I don't know can be overcome is that document conversion needs to be done through the browser on the client-side. The app must be able to take popular office document types and convert them to pdf, **before being sent to the server**.

I have been having a hard time finding info on anyone trying to do this or having done this. So any Ideas, or examples?

Note: The document must not leave the clients computer before conversion.

Edit: The documents do not have to be previewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Well... theoretically it can be done, but it would be a monumental task.

Options...
You can read the file into JavaScript as a blob, and then refer to the byte format from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615407%28v=office.14%29.aspx But you'd need to create custom Microsoft Office viewers in JavaScript and then write code that converts the views to postscript.

You can start with someone else's project. WebODF supports many document formats: https://github.com/kogmbh/WebODF and then look at a js PDF generator such as https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF to see if the two could be combined via a code fork.

IMO though, full support from these two example projects for your particular use case may be dubious, especially if the users are making complex documents. I imagine there's some intellectual property issue disallowing upload and server side conversion of an Office document, wherein you need to provide some PDF preview to the user before committing to an upload. Asking them to convert to PDF themselves is not a huge ask with free things like CutePDF, especially if a requirement is intended to protect them. Perhaps though the links and terminology used in this answer will give you a starting point for searching further.

Comment: They don't need to see the documents or even know they are being converted. Unfortunately it seems that the user not having to view the documents makes it only slightly less monumental.

Comment: Well, good luck in any case. I hope the two github links I shared at least help as a starting point for client side conversion.